# How to free up space of dvd drive

Tags: windows, vmware

I'm trying to install kali Linux on VMWare. But I click on iso file of kali Linux. Now when I open a file explorer I see that there is new DVD drive is shown with name "DVD Drive(F) Install Kali Linux" with space "0byte free of 379MB".

Now my question is that, does this new created DVD drive takes 379 MB of memory from my hard disk ? If yes then how should I delete this and recover this memory to my hard disk back. If not then where does this 379 MB of memory came from ?

Please tell the answer by keeping in mind I'm installing OS for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify things 379MB is the size of your Kali Linux (netinstall) ISO file, you don't have to free memory or delete anything, you just need to unmount (or eject) the virtual DVD on Windows side. This "memory", as you said, came from that...
If you double-click on any *.iso file on Windows, this will "mount" that virtual DVD (not virtual as virtual machine I mean), but this is not absolutely needed to get your job done.
To install a new VM (Kali) on VMWare you should create a new virtual machine inside that environment and attach the ISO file, then create a virtual HD and boot your newly created VM from ISO to complete the installation process. Netinstall ISOs needs an active internet connection to download packages during install stage, no differences between physical and virtual machines for that. So make sure you provided that too. Bye.